# How to get count of open db connections in java for postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql

I am running Java code with Postgres database and allowing 50 live connections. I want to know is there any way to get number of live connections. Also I want to know when those connections are created?

Comment: you need this in java program? else you can directly check these things with `pg_top`

Comment: Use "pg_stat_activity" docs - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: If u need to track own connections when set ApplicationName property in jdbc url to identify yours connections or u can use as well fields "usename" or "client_addr"